# maybe my questions are not in the right place

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that you generally seem to be unhappy with my questions. I also read that "Stack Overflow" may be a proper place for questions of such kind.

Should I turn to Stack Overflow for future questions?

Perhaps even for the past: should you and I transfer some of my existing questions from U&L to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer one part of this question: where should you write your questions?

In my opinion, the first place to look is each site's Help Center:

- [UNIX & Linux: What topics can I ask about here?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

  - Using or administering a *nix desktop or server
  - The Unix foundation underlying OS X (but generally not frontend application questions)
  - The underlying *nix OS on an embedded system or handheld device (e.g. an Android phone)
  - Shell scripting
  - Applications packaged in *nix distributions (note: being cross-platform does not disqualify)
  - UNIX C API and System Interfaces ( within reason )
- [Stack Overflow: What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

  - a specific programming problem, or
  - a software algorithm, or
  - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
  - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

There is some overlap in scope (you'll see lots of UNIX scripting and tool questions on SO; you'll see larger scripts and "algorithm"-type questions here at U&L), so if it's not yet clear which site you think is appropriate, you could search each site for similar questions. If there are none, reconsider whether the question is on-topic; you could ask here on Meta for additional guidance.

Separately, I would not recommend migrating existing questions, even if they are downvoted. If you decide that you'd rather post them elsewhere, please delete them (if you can) before re-asking on the new site; that way, there's no duplication of effort.

Comment: Also, [accepting answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (when appropriate) will often mean future questions attract more interested readers.

Answer (score 0):

> "I have noticed that you generally seem to be unhappy with my questions"

As far as I can feel *personally* concerned :

For having honestly tried to answer [one of your questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728430/in-less-how-to-enter-as-search-pattern/728433#728433), I must admit having downvoted it **after** reading the comments you made on my answer.
In particular [comment #3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728430/in-less-how-to-enter-as-search-pattern/728433#comment1382008_728433) *"Your editor…"* ???
Not to say [comment #6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728430/in-less-how-to-enter-as-search-pattern/728433#comment1382089_728433) that just made me wonder : "*How the hell can they think anyone can help ?*"

Because I do believe you are an honest contributer here, I would not want you to misunderstand my downvote :
I do not mean that I feel "*unhappy*" with your question (Would I have feel so that I would not have taken care to answer it (*1)) I even less mean that your question would better fit somewhere else.

I simply meant that from your comments, you were definitely not helping anyone to… help you.

Therefore… rather than believing that your questions would better fit elsewhere, please :

- Document your questions more,
- Interact with answers in a more detailed/rational way

And… everybody will just be happy with your questions… that I personally could even… upvote! :-)

Well… in short : Try harder ! ;-)

BTW never deduce from the votes that your question do not fit on U&L_SE… I personally very rarely score >0 on my own questions… but… still… asking… ;-)

---

**1 :** You can even notice that [Stephen kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) edited my answer and that [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) edited you question. Both are top contributors in U&L_SE… I am sure they would not have cared if *"being unhappy"* with your question.

Comment: Thanks, thus I anderstand have to wait to become unblocked. Regards.

Comment: @Kusalananda (or any other mod around) Could you help ? I just fail to understand. User Anton Wessel is being blocked ? (Whatever the reason, for)

Comment: @MC68020 once a user has asked several questions in quick succession, and those questions have been downvoted, SE blocks that user from opening new questions for a while. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt for the info I had missed. Well! From now on, I will think twice before downvoting a question… I just hate giving food to punishing bots.

Comment: @AntonWessel : From the reading of the page Stephen linked to in his comment above, I understand that NO! Don't just *wait" or, you'll have to wait for 6 months. DO rework your questions instead.